# Is there a way to limit the html page to a particular page size?

Tags: html, printing, thermal-printer

I am printing a normal page with sp90 driver for thermal printer.

```
<div>Hello test</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.print();
```

My div contains[image] a receipt.

The page size in sp90 driver for thermal printer is 80 by 3260 mm and there are no other options so it prints me a very long receipt which i want to avoid.

Please help

Is there a way to limit the html page to a particular page size?

Comment: you have try to print a receipt because in print preview show blank space but when print a page not display blank space.

Comment: you write css for print like @media print { your styles}

Comment: @vini: have you had an answer for that? or find out some work around this? I would really appreciate if you share that